# Waking up a sleeping thread using reflection

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a problem as follows: I've got the next class:

```
Public class foo{
   Thread runningThread = null;
   ...
   public static void start() {
       runningThread = new RunningThreadImpl();
       runningThread.start();
       runningThread.join();
   }
   public static void stop() {
       this.runningThread.stop();
   }
 }
```

And:

```
Public class runningThreadImpl implements Runnable {
...
public void run() {
     while (shouldRun()){
         sleep(... A long long time);
     }
}
public void stop() {
    shouldRun = false;
}
```

I've got a class using foo, And now i want it to stop. The above code defined inside a given jar, Which means i cannot edit it. But i thought about using Reflection in order to interrupt the Thread and "Wake" him up so i won't have to wait.

So far i've gotten this far:

```
 Field field = foo.getInstance().getClass().getDeclaredField("runningThread");
 field.setAccessible(true);
```

But i don't now what to do now. How can i use the Field in order to interrupt a thread? Is it even possible?

Comment: As i said, I can't edit the code of those classes. Legacy ;P

Comment: Get the value of `field` using `(Thread) field.get(foo.getInstance())`, and call `interrupt` on it?

Comment: How to do it? I'm getting an error for each 'get' i try to do.

Comment: Can you be a tiny bit more specific about the Error you get?

Comment: Why not copy/paste the old code into your new project and modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new class called FooHelper in the same package as Foo like so:

```
package same.package.as.foo;

public class FooHelper {
    private final Foo foo;
    public FooHelper(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.foo.stop();
        this.foo.runningThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Construct a FooHelper passing it the instance of Foo, and call the FooHelper's stop() method.